# Callback after_destroy not triggered through ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin for the backoffice of my application and I have these three models:

```
class Organization
  has_many :organization_collection_relations
  has_many :collections, through: :organization_collection_relations
end

class OrganizationCollectionRelation
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :collection

  after_destroy :do_something
end

class Collection
  has_many :organization_collection_relations
  has_many :organizations, through: :organization_collection_relations
end
```

In my edit page for the `Organization` I have and `f.input :collections`. The problem comes when I edit and organization and for example I remove all the collections. The `after_destroy` callback method `do_something` is not being triggered. So I have to do a workaround in the controller section of the active admin file.

```
controller do
  def update
    resource = Organization.find(params[:id])
    former_ids = resource.collection_ids
    super
    new_ids = resource.reload.collection_ids
    # my logic here
  end
end
```

I think there's a better way of handling this...

Answer (score 1):

Active Admin has its also own callbacks so you can use like below in organizations.rb file in the admin folder.

```
  after_destroy do |organization|
    # do your stuff
  end
```

I done it earlier for before_save and after_save I am not sure if its available for after_destroy or not you can check out [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb) more about active admin callbacks.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try with an `after_destroy` but with the `OrganizationCollectionRelation` model, which is the important one for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with the callback. The `after_destroy` callback of the `OrganizationCollectionRelation` model is not triggered by the edit of an `Organization`

Comment: do yo have file of organization_collection_relations.rb in active admin ??

Comment: Yes! I actually added the `after_detroy` in that file.

Comment: Can you please add which you code added and which error you get in after_destroy ?

Comment: I don't get any error, the after_destroy callback for `OrganizationCollectionRelation` is not being called when editing the model `Organization` and leaving the input for collections blank, although the OrganizationCollectionRelation gets destroyed because I see it in the logs and it is not present in the database

Comment: It should work , but i don't why its not working. How you check whether its going in before _destoy method or not ? do you put any debugger ? Are you using nested forms ? like within organization form destroying OrganizationCollectionRelation ? if it is then can you also try to add before_destory call back in organization model itself ?

Comment: I know it is weird it is not working. Just to let you know, I'm not using nested forms, I use directly the association Organization has many Collections and set in the permit params section of `Organization` in Active Admin `collection_ids: []`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try the `after_destory` method in the admin file  like

```
 after_destroy do |organization|
    organization.organization_collection_relations.each(&:do_something)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I have done the same
eg`

```
 after_destroy do |model1|
    account_id = model1.try(:account_id)
    Model2.do_something_method(account_id)
  end
```

But it did not worked for me, as I was using apartments for my project.So what I have done to make it work, I switched the apartment before calling the method.

```
 after_destroy do |model1|
    #here model1 is independent to apartment 
    account_id = model1.try(:account_id)
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!("account_#{account_id}")
    #Model2 is depended on apartment so we need to switch apartment before calling it
    Model2.do_something_method(account_id)
  end
```