# Can anyone tell me why after_destroy is not working in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

I am using rails 5 and active_admin 2.0.0

I am using a callback in active admin like below

```
  after_destroy do |my_model|
    account_id = my_model.try(:account_id)
    Account.desable_something(account_id)
  end
```

But this callback is not working after deleting data.

I have tried this before in my model file file but it was working for some environments not for all. Then after i used this approach to use in in admin file it is not working there also.

Comment: “is not working” isn't a very precise error description. What exactly is happening? Is the callback not called as expected? Or is there an error message? What does it say?

Answer (score -1):

In Rails, there are two methods for deleting records from the database: destroy and delete. The difference between them is that destroy will trigger callbacks (such as after_destroy), while delete will not.

In your case, if you're using the destroy method to delete data, the after_destroy callback should be triggered. However, if you are using the delete method, the callback won't be triggered.

Comment: Try to give a sample how to use `after_destroy` to be used.

Comment: You are right we have two methods.But in my case I was using apartments.So what I have done to make it work, I switched the apartment before calling the method.

for reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734257/callback-after-destroy-not-triggered-through-activeadmin/77132043#77132043